# How to highlight a Cell in a table based on a called out cell address entered in Excel

Tags: excel

I am trying to highlight a cell inside a table which i like to show by entering the cell address(eg:$G$7) in another cell. Can anyone good in Excel help me and explain and guide me the steps to achieve this. Many thanks!

Answer (score 0):

This can be done with conditional formatting using a formula like:

```
=AND(ROW()=ROW(INDIRECT($A$1)),COLUMN()=COLUMN(INDIRECT($A$1)))
```

(note this formula assumes you will enter the address of the cell in `A1`)

To apply it, select all the relevant cells (the ones you want the formatting on), then add conditional formatting to then with the above formula.